# How to access a var of my class in the application delegate?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm currently creating a new component for developpers and, because I want it to be really simply easy to integrate, I would like to be able to see if it has been created inside the application delegate, and if so, I would like to access it and be able to call its methods.

I was hoping the answer should be in something like this :

```
Class clazz = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] class];

unsigned int varCount;

Ivar *ivars = class_copyIvarList(clazz, &varCount);

for (int i = 0; i < varCount; i++) {
    Ivar var = ivars[i];

    NSString *typeEncoding = [NSString stringWithCString:ivar_getTypeEncoding(var) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *name         = [NSString stringWithCString:ivar_getName(var) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

}
```

But my problem is that, with that code, I'm able to found my initialized component... But how can I access it ?

I've tried this :

```
if ([typeEncoding isEqualToString:@"@\"MyClassName\""]) {
        MyClassName *myclass = (MyClassName *)object_getIvar(self, var);
    }
```

Without success (it doesn't point on the good component)...

Does someone have a solution on this ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay,

Finally I found it myself.

The method to access the founded var from the application delegate is the following :

```
if ([typeEncoding isEqualToString:@"@\"MyClassName\""]) {
    MyClassName *myclass = (MyClassName *)object_getIvar([[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate], var);
}
```

With this line, myclass now point on the good var from the application delegates and is able to call methods from it (tried with an internal method created for that)...

Hope this will help someone...